# Lumen data store as hours minute and second format

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen to build an API. At first, I want to explain my work a little 
  bit. My API will provide an content to a user. The user will record the content 
  and submit it with audio length. (EX: 1min. 22 sec.)

I just store it in my 
  database. when the user wants to see how many hours he recorded I will return 
  the total time. okay... that's why i was created a table column

```
$table->decimal('audio_length');
```

and store it how user sends request. when the user wants to see the total 
   time my code will work like:

```
$point = PointSpeech::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    $total_point = 0;

    foreach ($point as $value) {
        $total_point += $value->points_pending;

    }
    return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'point_pending' => $total_point], 200);
```

yeah I know it's a stupid way. Now I looking for a better way to show it as 
   Hour, Minute and Second. hi, can you guys help me...? please...?

Comment: Plz dump the $total_point

Answer (score 2):

When you're storing the duration in this way, you should always convert to the smallest unit you want to record. In your case, if you don't care about milliseconds (or smaller), you should convert the time given by the user to seconds e.g. 1 minute 22 seconds, would be 82 seconds.

This is the number you should store in the database. If you do care about smaller units such as milliseconds, then that is what you should store in the database. Store an *integer* value.

Now when pulling your information out of the database, you can do a simple `SUM` to get the total number of seconds (or milliseconds) and convert that back to display to the user.

Converting to hours, minutes and seconds should be easy enough to do once you have an integer representing seconds. As an example:

```
$seconds = 176; // This would come from your database query

echo (new DateTime('@0'))
    ->diff(new DateTime("@$seconds"))
    ->format('%h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
```